# SVG tag in bootstrap 4 with viewBox attr resizes unpredictably

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-4

I'm starting to make a site design responsive, starting with the SVG logo. As per the [outstanding recommendations by Amelia Bellamy-Royds](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/), I've added attrs for `viewBox,preserveAspectRatio, x, y, width`, and `height`.

I'm having lots of issues, but the two that really have me puzzled are:

1) When I shrink my browser, the navigation links disappear (even though the logo remains the same size,) then past the medium breakpoint, the SVG gets huge.

[image: animation of screen resizing with inconsistent svg size]

Why does the svg resize so dramatically?

2) My current viewBox is `viewBox="0 0 349 54"`.  When I *decrease* those numbers, say to 0 0 175 25, the svg gets *larger*. When I *increase* them, say to 0 0 3500 540, the image gets *smaller*.  Except *sometimes*, where decreasing the numbers decreases the size. How is it that changing those numbers arbitrarily increases or decreases the svg size?

Here is the relevant navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-toggleable-md hidden-print"
     style="height:4em">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand"
         href="/">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 349 54"
             preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
             x="0"
             y="0"
             width="100%"
             height="100%">
          <!-- SVG data goes here -->
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-inverse hidden-md-up navbar-toggler-left"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        ☰
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary"
           id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"
               href="/home">
              <i class="fa fa-home"
                 aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Home
            </a>
          </li>

          [ ... ]

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"
               href="/logout">
              <i class="fa fa-sign-out"
                 aria-hidden="true"></i>
              logout
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>  <!-- end collapsing navbar -->
    </div>  <!-- end col 10 -->
  </div>  <!-- end row -->
</nav>
```

Thanks for taking a look.  The relevant css is below.  These are all the selectors I have overridden or added to the stock bootstrap 4 alpha 6 release:

```
body {
  padding-top:6rem;
}

body, html {
  height:100%;
}

/* workaround modal-open padding issue */
body.modal-open {
    padding-right:0 !important;
}


#sidebar {
   padding-left:0;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #001A57;
}

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
.bottom-buffer { margin-bottom:.5rem; display: inline-block; }

/*
 * Off Canvas at medium breakpoint
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {

  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -33%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 33%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

/*
 * Off Canvas wider at sm breakpoint
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 34em) {
  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -45%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 45%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    width: 45%;
  }
}


/* responsive nav stacked liked 3.x */
@media(max-width:34em) {
    .navbar .navbar-brand {
        float:none;
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
        float: none;
        margin-left: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
    }
}

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  -webkit-align-self: inherit;
      -ms-flex-item-align: inherit;
          align-self: inherit;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: .5em;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a css issue, can you post your css that effects the header?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I've edited the post to include css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Your SVG gets *huge* because you've told it to take up the available space with `width="100%"`. When the navbar collapses into the hamburger icon it fills the remaining space. If you didn't have a `width` attribute it would still fill the remaining space.

**2)** The `viewBox` defines an independent user coordinated space. This is separate from the viewport coordinate space that your SVG elements to be drawn on. Don't confuse `viewBox` values with setting actual dimensions for the SVG.

Initially the user coordinate space is identical to the viewport coordinate space until you define some values for `viewBox` that *"change things up."*

I like to think of the `viewBox` as a *"window"* to the SVG in the viewport coordinate space. The parameters for `viewBox` are `x y width height`. The first to values of `viewBox` state where to start the `viewBox` in relation to the viewport coordinate space and the last two values provide its dimensions.

Please pay close attention to the `viewBox` values, the `<rect>` attributes will remain constant in each example. I've included a pink dot for reference when adjusting the `viewBox`.

Notice that the gold box is started `5` from the right and `5` down from the upper left corner of the viewport coordinate space origin of `0,0`.

#### Gold box centered in `viewBox`.

`viewBox` starts with same origin as viewport coordinate space.

Gold box starts `5` from the right is `20` wide so `viewBox` needs third parameter to be at least `25` to show the whole box. To create equal whitespace we add `5` to width for a total of `30`.

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="20" height="20" fill="gold"/>
</svg>
```

#### `viewBox` starts in the middle of gold box.

`viewBox` starts with at `15,15` of viewport coordinate space.

Gold box is offset by `5` to start and half of its width is `10`,

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="15 15 30 30">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="20" height="20" fill="gold"/>
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1" fill="hotpink"/>
</svg>
```

#### `viewBox` twice the size of initial example.

`viewBox` starts with same origin as viewport coordinate space.

The `viewBox` is now showing a `60x60` section of the viewport coordinate space. Since the gold box is drawn and positioned in a space smaller than `60x60`, you see a lot more of the viewport coordinate space than before.

This creates a zoom out effect.

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="20" height="20" fill="gold"/>
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1" fill="hotpink"/>
</svg>
```

#### `viewBox` half the size of initial example.

`viewBox` starts with same origin as viewport coordinate space.

The `viewBox` is now showing a `15x15` section of the viewport coordinate space. Since the gold box is drawn and positioned in a space greater than that of the `viewBox`, you only see a portion of the gold box.

This creates a zoom in effect.

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="20" height="20" fill="gold"/>
  <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="1" fill="hotpink"/>
</svg>
```

**I'll try to fill in some more details later.

Comment: This is really great information!  Thank you. I won't say I understand it all (partially because some of the behavior I'm seeing locally countermands the info you have here, not sure why) but your answer helped me get past the issue.